# Editing NBT in Obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos

I'm trying to make an app on iOS that edits a .dat file but I'm not entirely sure how to edit it because its in NBT format can someone help me out?

Comment: It's a zipball, so you'll need to use libGzip to deflate it and then work with the actual dat files.

Comment: @CodaFi That's only for PC edition. Minecraft Pocket Edition does not zip the level.dat what so ever, so you can open the file using a hex editor or read it via input stream and get all the data you need without unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [NBT library in C](https://github.com/FliPPeh/cNBT), you would have to both remove the unzip/deflate code (since Minecraft Pocket does not zip level.dat files) and convert it to obj-c, but it should work for you.